# In Ruby how does it work when passing "self" when initialising a class?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, initialization, self

I've come across the following solution to a problem and am struggling to understand the `attach_tail!` method. How exactly does this `Knot.new(self)` work? In a general sense, what does it to do pass self when you create a new instance of the class?

The idea of the programme is more extensive than this and essentially is about the head of a 'knot' moving around a grid and being followed by the tail with more methods inside the class that i havent included.

```
class Knot
  attr_reader :x, :y, :head, :tail

  def initialize(head=nil)
    @x = @y = 0     # Position at the start is 0,0
    @head = head    # Head is passed, but the default is nil
    @tail = nil     # Tail is nil to begin with
  end

  def attach_tail!
    @tail = Knot.new(self)   # Tail can then be added
  end

  def location = [x, y]
end
```

Comment: Here [`self`](https://www.bootrails.com/blog/ruby-self/) is the current instance. So in this case the constructor takes a `head` (parent) object, that is `nil` by default. When you create a `tail` (child) you create a new instance with the current instance as head (and simultaneously registering the new instance as tail (child) . Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about `self` nor about "initializing a class" here.

`new` is a method like any other method, and the object referenced by `self` is an object like any other object.

Instead of

> ```ruby
> Knot.new(self)
> ```

It could be

```ruby
Knot.new(baz)
```

or

```ruby
foo.bar(self)
```

or

```ruby
foo.bar(baz)
```

You are simply calling a method on an object and passing another object as an argument. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to see this from the outside.

For demonstration purposes, let's briefly change `attr_reader` to [`attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#attr_accessor-method) in order to make all attributes settable from the outside:

```
class Knot
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :head, :tail

  # ...
end
```

With the above and a given knot `a`:

```
a = Knot.new
```

we could attach a tail to `a` via:

```
a.tail = Knot.new(a)
```

`Knot.new(a)` creates a new knot with `a` as its `head`. It then assigns that new knot to the `tail` of `a`.

Now, if you wanted to move that assignment from outside the object into the object, `a` would have to somehow pass *itself* as an argument to `Knot.new`. And this is exactly what `self` does – within instance methods, `self` refers to the current instance.

Outside `a`:

```
a.tail = Knot.new(a)
```

Inside `a`:

```
self.tail = Knot.new(self)
```

And without the `tail=` accessor, we'd assign to the instance variable directly:

```
@tail = Knot.new(self)
```

Which is exactly what `attach_tail!` does.